# Fixing Width of WellPanel irrespective of Browser page width

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

I created a Shiny dashboard in line of below codes :

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(

  sidebarMenuOutput("menu"),
  conditionalPanel("input.tabs == 'ABC'",
    fluidRow(
      column(11, offset = 1, h5((' Note')))
    )
  ),
  conditionalPanel("input.tabs == 'ABC1'",
    fluidRow(
      column(11, offset = 1, style = "height:20px; color:rgb(30,144,255);", h1((' Update')))
    )
  ))

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "ABC1",br())

  ),
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "ABC",br(),

fixedRow(column(10, offset = 1, wellPanel()))


)

  )
)


ui = dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "ABC"),
  sidebar,
  body
)

server = function(input, output){
  output$menu <- renderMenu({
    sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
      menuItem("ABC", tabName="ABC", icon=icon("line-chart"), selected=TRUE),
      menuItem("ABC1", tabName="ABC1", icon=icon("line-chart"))
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

With above setup, the width of WellPanel getting changed if I resize my Browser. Therefore, this looks ugly when I see my App in bigger screen (e.g. 2560 x 1080). I want entire size of WellPanel will remain fixed. If Browser size is smaller than WellPanel then, some horizontal/vertical scroll bar will appear. And if bigger then, Wellpanel will stay in the top-middle part of the Browser.

Any idea what setting needs to be changed in my above code to achieve this.

Thanks,

Comment: You can include `tags$head(tags$style(type = "text/css", '.well{width: 600px}'))` in the `fluidRow()` to fix the width. However, either `overflow:auto !important;` nor `overflow:scroll !important;` is working for me,...maybe i find sthg in the evening,...

Comment: Thanks for insight. But it is impacting all WellPanels in App. I want such fixed-width WellPanel only for "ABC", not for all. Secondly, when I resizing my Browser, that impacted WellPanel is not exactly moving to the center of my screen. Any further adjustment is required to accomplish both of above?

Comment: Anybody could help me out on fixing above. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think this works:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  
  sidebarMenuOutput("menu"),
  conditionalPanel("input.tabs == 'ABC'",
                   fluidRow(
                     column(11, offset = 1, h5((' Note')))
                   )
  ),
  conditionalPanel("input.tabs == 'ABC1'",
                   fluidRow(
                     column(11, offset = 1, style = "height:20px; color:rgb(30,144,255);", h1((' Update')))
                   )
  ))

body <- dashboardBody(
  tags$head(tags$style(type = "text/css"
                       , '#plotUI {min-width: 570px; max-width: 570px;overflow:auto;}'
  )
)
  ,tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "ABC1",br())
    
  ),
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "ABC",br(),
            
            fluidRow(column(10, offset = 1
                            ,div(class="thiswell"
                            , wellPanel(
                                        style= "min-width: 600px;max-width: 600px;overflow:auto",
                                        ,uiOutput("plotUI")
                              
                            )
                            )
                            ) )
            
            
    )
    
  )
)

ui = dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "ABC"),
  sidebar,
  body
)

server = function(input, output){
  output$menu <- renderMenu({
    sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
                menuItem("ABC", tabName="ABC", icon=icon("line-chart"), selected=TRUE),
                menuItem("ABC1", tabName="ABC1", icon=icon("line-chart"))
    )
  })
  
  output$plotUI<- renderUI({
    plotOutput("thePlot")
  })
  
  output$thePlot<- renderPlot({
    plot(1:10)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```